# Split pdf with pdftk (closed)

Tags: powershell, pdf, pdftk

Im searching several pdf´s in a folder for a certain keyword. If keyword is found i want to split the pdf at the certain page and save it as a new pdf.
Code:

```
Add-Type -Path '...\itextsharp.5.5.13.1 (1)\lib\itextsharp.dll'
$pdfs = gci "C:\Users\..\Plan\" *.pdf
$keywords = "TEST"
$pdftk = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe"
$output = "C:\Users\...\new"
$newpdf = New-Object -TypeName psobject 
foreach($pdf in $pdfs) {

    Write-Host "processing -" $pdf.FullName

    # prepare the pdf
    $reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList $pdf.FullName

    # for each page
    for($page = 1; $page -le $reader.NumberOfPages; $page++) {

        # set the page text
        $pageText = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($reader,$page).Split([char]0x000A)

        # if the page text contains keyword
            if($pageText -match $keywords) {
                break                             
            }
    }

    #$reader.Close()
    $FirstPage = $page
    $LastPage = $reader.NumberOfPages

    Write-Host "Starting page is: " $FirstPage
    Write-Host "Last page is: " $LastPage

    & $pdftk $pdf.FullName cat $FirstPage-end output "$output\test.pdf"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `output` keyword. Use

```
$pdftk $pdf.FullName cat $FirstPage-end output "$output\test.pdf"
```

The reason you get this weird error is that C is being interpreted as a handle, that is a pointer to a previous input file.